# SortedMap vs CheckedSortedMap vs synchronizedSortedMap

Tags: java, collections

Can anyone help me to figure out difference between
SortedMap, CheckedSortedMap, synchronizedSortedMap.
I am really have trouble in making decision which one to use when?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which one to use and when to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SortedMap` is an interface that is a Map(key-value pairs) with an added contract of being ordered in some defined manner on its keys. Owing to that ordering of keys SortedMap has extra methods like `SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)`, `SortedMap<K,V> headMap(K toKey) ...` which 'normal' Maps dont have. If you iterate a keyset of a sortedMap you will find a definite order.

A `Treemap` is an implementation of that interface. If you are creating a new SortedMap object by yourself, its almost always go for `TreeSet`.

For `checkedSortedMap` or any other `Collections.checkedXXX()` methods, Here is a fine discussion on what they all are for: [What is the Collections.checkedList() call for in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161176/what-is-the-collections-checkedlist-call-for-in-java)

Classes in Collections framework are not synchronized by default. For Maps it means that if you have a map that is shared between two or more threads and one is doing a `put(A, value)` and another thread is also calling `put(A, othervalue)` at the same time on the map, strange things can occur. `Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(sortedMap)` method gives a synchronized map that wraps the given map and with proper locking mechanisms in place.

Answer (score 1):

`SortedMap` is an interface, which is implemented by `ConcurrentSkipListMap, TreeMap` classes.

Use `Collections.synchronizedSortedMap` to get thread safe (synchronized) view of sorted map. Useful in multithreaded environment.

Use `java.util.Collections.checkedSortedMap` to get a dynamically typesafe view of the specified sorted map.