# How to remove 'Type Safety'/'Unchecked conversion' warning from returning generic List in Java?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, warnings, hibernate-annotations

I'm performing the following operation in Java using Hibernate inside my data access object:

```
public List<Device> getDevices() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Device").list();
}
```

This gives me the following warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to     List<Device>
```

In order to remove the warning I'm using

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

but I'm looking for a better way to remove this warning and ideally deal with something other than 'Device' from being returned from the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115692/how-to-avoid-type-safety-warnings-with-hibernate-hql-results?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding Type Safety Warnings Using Hibernate Query.list()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651176/avoiding-type-safety-warnings-using-hibernate-query-list)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367626/how-do-i-fix-the-expression-of-type-list-needs-unchecked-conversion

Answer (score 3):

Java does not have reified generics, so sadly you can not get rid of the annotations :(
If you search for this on SO, one of the most often recommended solutions is to use [Collections.checkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161176/what-is-the-collections-checkedlist-call-for-in-java), which might be helpful here

Answer (score 1):

Since you put the `spring` tag in your question I assume that you are already using Spring. In that case using [SpringData](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) and JPA instead of Hibernate-specific stuff would be much easier. Otherwise you can't really get rid of the warning because you can't change the api.

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate session object will not return a typed Query.  You can utilize an EntityManager instead (which hibernate supports), which does allow you to specify type on createQuery().